# Ошибка: Неразрешенный внешний символ "_main"

Tags: c++, opengl

Здравствуйте!
Я тоже написала эту программу. У вас случайно не выскакивала ошибка

> `my.cpp
>   msvcrt.lib(crtexe.obj) : error LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ "_main"
>   c:\users\виктория\documents\visual studio 2010\Projects\my_GL1\Release\my_GL1.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 неразрешенных внешних элементов`

Пожалуйста, подскажите, как ее можно устранить?

Answer (score 3):

Подобная проблема будет иметь место, если вместо приложения Win32 вы создали консольное приложение Win32. В это случае будет отсутствовать точка входа main и сборщик будет выдавать ошибку.

Чтобы исправить, надо создать проект заново как приложение Win32 и добавить в него код. Дополнительно здесь: [ошибка LNK2001: неразрешенный внешний символ _main](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/291952).

Comment: Совсем необязательно пересоздавать проект, достаточно просто указать где-то в Project properties подсистему - Windows (скорее всего сейчас там установлено Console)

Answer (score 1):

Можно просто изменить тут:
Проект->Свойства->Компоновщик->Система->Подсистема
на Консоль (/SUBSYSTEM:CONSOLE) или Windows (/SUBSYSTEM:WINDOWS) (в зависимости от того, какая подсистема вам нужна